# Bootstrap Certificate Problems in IE 8/IE 9

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, ssl-certificate, self-signed

We are having problems with some browsers attempting to get Bootstrap 3 (js and css) from the documented CDN (https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js).  The main two browsers are IE8 and IE9 and we don't have option of telling client to upgrade.  Other high level browsers (even IE11) seem to work properly.

We've had to resort to hosting files ourselves, but obviously I would much rather reference the CDN.

For a simple example, in IE11, if I do the following:

1) Type following in url...
[image]

2) Hit enter...
[image]

3) Click Run...
[image]

Now, IE11 will actually continue and run (obviously script will error out), but all these warnings are my best guess as to what might be tripping up IE8/9 (and maybe other lower level browsers).  As I said, I've temporarily hosted the files on our own secure.benefittech.com domain, and no warnings occur when I do same steps.

Here are some screen shots from client browser (IE8) when attempting to run the real site referencing CDN urls.

This first one is showing the debugger not knowing what the .tooltip() method is (from Bootstrap.min.js).

[image]

Finally, this is the IE security bar warning they get when hitting the site

[image]

Any ideas on how this might be resolved or what info I could supply MaxCDN with to try and resolve this would be greatly appreciated - or do we have to continue to host files ourselves?

I realize IE8/9 are old browsers (neither of which I'd be running at this time), but as mentioned earlier, I don't have option to force client to upgrade and surprised no one else has raised this issue (when I contacted MaxCDN, they were surprised by the issue, but not being experienced in Certificate 'technology/language', I didn't really know what to provide them.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a test environment with IE8/9 where you could do some tests? It could be a problem with certificate chain building. Maybe some certs in the chain are not trusted.

Could you import SubCA certificate from `http://secure.globalsign.com/cacert/gsdomainvalsha2g2r1.crt` to intermediate CA store and Root CA from `http://secure.globalsign.net/cacert/Root-R1.crt`?

SubCA certificate (GlobalSign Domain Validation CA - SHA256 - G2) is pretty new (issued 20.02.2014) so if IE8/9 does not follow authority info access from end entity certificate (to build certificate chain) or it does not handle well that the certificate of subCA is in PEM format at `http://secure.globalsign.com/cacert/gsdomainvalsha2g2r1.crt` (should be DER IMO) or if by any chance GlobalSign Root CA is not trusted by IE8/9 then I believe this could be the reason for the IE warnings.

Comment: From developer, "I guess my response to that answer would be that you obviously don't control the servers which could incorporate a full certificate chain in the PEM and you need to resolve this for general IE8/9 use, not your personal use.  And I think they are right that IE8/9 just doesn't register that root certificate."  That was his response - bear in mind we aren't certificate experts, so not sure if the 'language' is all right, but hopefully close enough to provide some insight.